# What am I doing wrong when trying to install Bitnami modules into a LAMP stack

Tags: wordpress, bitnami, ubuntu-server

When I first uploaded the basic LAMP stack from Bitnami, it was just one .run file.  I first was making the mistake of not writing it like this:

```
./bitnami-lamp-stack.run
```

Note, full file name was longer, obviously.  So, then to install WordPress, there is a native installer.  So, I uploaded that, just as instructed.  Made it executable.  Then ran

```
./bitnami-wordpress-module.run
```

Note, again, the actual fine name was different.  So, the second command, should find the bitnami installation and add WordPress.  Strangely, it just returns immediately without doing anything.  I tried it with an without sudo, as I had given read and execute permission temporarily.  It just throws me back at the command prompt having done nothing.

I even tried running it from the same directory as where the lamp stack is installed.  I am baffled by this and stumped.  One idea did come to mind...  Maybe I need to add the bitnami lamp stack location to the path.  It doesn't seem to require that but who knows.
This is on Ubuntu 14.04.
Thanks in advance for any help,
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you already have the Bitnami LAMP properly installed and you have troubles installing the module on top of the LAMP. Could you run the module installer with the following option?

`./bitnami-wordpress-module.run --mode text`

Could you also try to download again the module from the bitnami page and check the md5 of both installers? You can check it with the following command:

`md5sum /path/to/installer`

Comment: It appears that bitnami was not the best solution for my need.  I could be wrong but I think the idea of installing modules onto a base WAMP stack does not work for the Linux LAMP stack.  I am able to install a stack that includes WordPress on Ubuntu Linux, but I don't think Bitnami has "modules" that install on top of a LAMP stack.  Indeed, it is trivial to setup a LAMP stack and then WordPress in the htdocs folder or install their WordPress stack which includes the LAMP stack components.